# 'cannot find symbol error' when attempting to use .stream() on array in Java

Tags: java, stream, reduce

I am attempting to implement the Java.stream() method to multiple a list of numbers together in Java 8. I have imported the java.util.stream*; package. The static method is set to return an int and take in an array. However, when I call .stream().reduce() on the array, I get the error:

```
error: cannot find symbol
    int count = x.stream().reduce(1, (a, b) -> a * b).sum();
                 ^
  symbol:   method stream()
  location: variable x of type int[]
```

How can I properly use the stream() method to multiple the values of the array together in order?

The class I have defined as:

```
import java.util.stream.*;
public class Kata{
  public static int grow(int[] x){
    int count = x.stream().reduce(1, (a, b) -> a * b).sum();
    return count;  
  }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need `Arrays.stream` to convert an array into a stream:

```
int count = Arrays.stream(x).reduce(1, (a, b) -> a * b);
```

The `sum()` step you were doing at the end doesn't make sense, because after `reduce` we are already left with just a single primitive integer.  So I removed it.

Answer (score 2):

First convert array into `List` to stream it, or you can also use `Arrays.stream(x)` as @Tim Biegeleisen suggestion

```
Arrays.asList(x).stream(x).reduce(1, (a, b) -> a * b);
```

Comment: isn't `Arrays.asList(x).stream().reduce(1, (a, b) -> a * b);` enough? I don't understand the use of the x passed as a parameter to stream